# Unable to resolve file path when adding TypeScript to existing create react app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I'm trying to add TypeScript to my existing create-react-app project as mentioned [here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-typescript).

When I rename a file to `tsx` and restart the server I get the following error in the `App.js` file where the `tsx` file is imported like `import Team from './components/pages/Team'` this.

`Module not found: Can't resolve`

I also noticed that `tsconfig.json` file was not auto-generated when I added typescript( as mentioned in the above link )

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is here and facing this issue, my problem was with a version of `react-scripts`

> this feature is available with react-scripts@2.1.0 and higher.

I was in `2.0.3` and updating to the latest fixed the issue.